# Find OneDrive space usage?

Tags: onedrive

How do I find out how much space I have used on OneDrive?

Just trying to find how I can check for my space used.  I can't seem to find it on computer at the moment.  Tried to login to OneDrive and got nowhere.

Comment: Hey Kathy, can you please mark the answer as accepted if it resolves your issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

If you login at https://onedrive.live.com  then click the menu button, you will see the amount of used storage at the bottom of the menu.